# How to get all shared accounts list in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am very new to sales-force, In sales-force  the owner can manually share the account with another user. I need a list that shows the manual sharing of all accounts.Would it be possible by using apex class or trigger or any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Examine the `AccountShare` table, especially something like that:

```
SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, UserOrGroupId 
FROM AccountShare
WHERE RowCause IN ('Manual', 'TerritoryManual')
LIMIT 100
```

You can read up more about the values [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm), there's also a nice example of Apex used to share records based on rules that can't be expressed in normal sharing rules.

`UserOrGroupId` is tricky one -> if it will start with "005" that's an userid and your search is done. Otherwise you'll have to look it up in `Group` table. This will contain real groups (called "Public Groups" in the setup) as well as system-generated groups that correspond to Queues, Roles, Roles+Subordinates, Territories etc. So you might have a bit of recursive world of pain here trying to learn who actually is in this group.

I admit I was lucky in the past, level of nesting I saw in the Group table was never > 2 levels deep.